# In clash of clans, how are attackable resources distributed between buildings? 2016 Edition

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have to re-ask this question since the update now stores more resources in the Town Hall...

How are resources distributed between storage facilities, including the Town Hall?

Examples:(3)

1. When my Dark E storage wasn't full my town hall showed that it included Dark E so it has to be filling both at the same time.
2. When my Dark E storage was full my town hall was only filled to less than 80%.  So the storage and the Town Hall don't fill at the same %.
   *This included my farming more and the building didn't equalize like in part 3

   3. My gold storage always appeared to try and equalize by %. So if a level 1 storage had 60% then my level 11 also had 60%.   IF I was raided and they stole from one building but not the other when I clicked on a mine it would equalize.  It wouldn't only dump all the gold from the mine into the lesser of the two storage but would also take gold from the storage that had more to force the same % between the two storage containers.

So... how does storage in 2016 with the update now work?  If any of my personal examples are wrong tell me, please.

Comment: +1 For mentioning specifically post-update. Although, your title could mention the update more specifically instead of 2016

Answer (score 1):

Your townhall simply acts like another storage. Distribution of loot among storages happen like this. However much of a resource you have is evenly distributed among your storages of that type. If one of your storages holds less than the rest, once it is full, the amount that would be put into it if it were to be able to hold more is instead evenly distributed among the remaining storages. The only thing that changed is that townhall's can hold more resources. Storage for each collector is independent of each other, and is based on how much it has produced since it was last collected from.

Comment: The Town Hall always holds less loot than the rest of the storages

Comment: @PythonMaster not always. it depends on the levels of both the storages and the th